# Mounting a hard disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

I am new to Linux environment. I added a hard disk to my system. I am running Enterprise Linux Machine. It is not mounting my hard disk. Can any one tell me how to mount it?

Thanks,
Narendra

Comment: Do you know that there is a special Ubuntu site? http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Enterprise Linux is Redhat, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

With the command `dmesg`, find the name of your disk, like sdb.
After, you can create a folder in `/mnt`, like `/mnt/disk`.

To mount it: `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disk`

Comment: You need to mount a specific partition like `sdb1`. I already edited your answer. Also, you may need to provide the fs type.